# "Allocation Type" menu disabled in Instruments

Tags: ios, xcode, instruments

I've been watching the **410 - Fixing Memory Issues** session from the WWDC 2013. The first demo showed a distinction between *All Heap Allocations* and *All VM Regions*. I've tried to see that same information for my own app, but in my case **Allocation Type** menu is disabled, as shown on the screenshot below:

[image: Instruments]

I've used a default "Allocations" document in Instruments.
I've seen [similar question](https://devforums.apple.com/message/857428#857428) asked on the Developer Forums, but it doesn't contain an answer.

What should I do to enable this menu?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It turns out that `Allocation type` menu is active only while profiling on the real device.